# Abort due to constraint violation columns GroupId, idx are not unique

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm using FluentNHibernate and have done a many-to-many mapping but when I try to save my entity I get the following error:

```
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException
: could not insert collection: [Test.Entities.Recipient.Groups#b6815d34-f436-4142-9b8e-1bfcbf25509e][SQL: SQL not available]
---- System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : Abort due to constraint violation
columns GroupId, idx are not unique
```

Here is my mapping:

```
public class GroupMap : ClassMap<Group>
{
    public GroupMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.SenderName);
        Map(x => x.Created);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Recipients)
            .AsList()
            .WithTableName("groups_recipients")
            .WithParentKeyColumn("GroupId")
            .WithChildKeyColumn("RecipientId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class RecipientMap : ClassMap<Recipient>
{
    public RecipientMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
        Map(x => x.Firstname);
        Map(x => x.Lastname);
        Map(x => x.Phone);
        Map(x => x.Email);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Groups)
            .AsList()
            .WithTableName("groups_recipients")
            .WithParentKeyColumn("RecipientId")
            .WithChildKeyColumn("GroupId")
            .LazyLoad().Cascade.None();
    }
}
```

The problem seems to have something to do with the relationship tables id but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Cheers,
nandarya

Comment: First of all, you could set show_sql to true :) Helps a lot while debugging.. Hint for printing to the debut.out window: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/6ebcfadf-042d-4295-8902-5b3e039ab1b5

Comment: Actually I have "SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().ShowSql()" set so I should get the SQL. But in the error message I get: 
[SQL: SQL not available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AsList() was not a good idea. Should be AsBag(). And everything seems to work.

Comment: Seems to happen with certain One-to-many mappings as well. Using AsBag() solves the problem